# I accidentally uploaded a windows pointer instead of the actual folder- how do I delete it?

Tags: windows, git, symlink, lnk, git-rm

I accidentally uploaded a windows pointer instead of the actual folder- how do I delete it?
[image: File/Folder can't be deleted]

Here's my problem- I can't rm this folder.  It's an issue because I can't upload the real folder because it already exists.
My workaround is to upload a new folder name, but how do I clean this up?

There is no team here, I am the only user of this Git.

Comment: Did you try `-f` force rm and push?

Comment: Yes, but I get: "fatal: pathspec 'src' did not match any files". But you can see in the image that there is a file  (Windows link) in my repository.

Comment: Windows links have the (hidden) file extension `.lnk`. Try force removing `src.lnk`

Comment: Thanks, @daniel, but- same error:   '$ git rm -f src.lnk' gives me 
'fatal: pathspec 'src.lnk' did not match any files'